# PostgreSQL 16: cannot drop a tsvector column

Tags: postgresql

I have the IMDB database in PostgreSQL 16, with the table `title_basics`. The table contains several columns, including `titleSearchCol` which is of type `tsvector`. When I try to get rid of the column using psql with

`ALTER TABLE title_basics DROP COLUMN titleSearchCol;`

PostgreSQL throws an error

`ERROR:  column "titlesearchcol" of relation "title_basics" does not exist`

I can query the table, add more columns and drop other columns using the same syntax just fine. I have tried the postgres superuser as well, resulting in the same error message.

Querying the table with `SELECT *...` shows the column and its contents. `\d title_basics` also shows the column.

```
imdb_base=> \d title_basics

Table "public.title_basics"
Column        Type               Collation Nullable Default
-----------------------------------------------------------
tconst         character varying           not null
titletype      character varying
primarytitle   character varying
originaltitle  character varying
isadult        boolean
startyear      numeric
endyear        numeric
runtimeminutes character varying
genres         character varying
titleSearchCol tsvector

Indexes:
"title_basics_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree(tconst)

Referenced by:                                                     
TABLE "title_akas" CONSTRAINT "title_akas_title_basics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (titleid) REFERENCES title_basics(tconst) NOT VALID
TABLE "title_crew" CONSTRAINT "title_crew_title_basics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (tconst) REFERENCES title_basics(tconst) NOT VALID
TABLE "title_episode" CONSTRAINT "title_episode_title_basics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (parenttconst) REFERENCES title_basics(tconst) NOT VALID
TABLE "title_principals" CONSTRAINT "title_principals_title_basics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (tconst) REFERENCES title_basics(tconst) NOT VALID
TABLE "title_ratings" CONSTRAINT "title_ratings_title_basics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (tconst) REFERENCES title_basics(tconst) NOT VALID
```

Comment: Please add to your question what exactly shows `\d title_basics`?

Comment: I have added the output to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, there's no column `titlesearchcol`, but there are column `titleSearchCol`. Someone had created that column with capital letters in name (using quotes), and now it only possible to use that column using quotes, like that:
`ALTER TABLE title_basics DROP COLUMN "titleSearchCol";`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this results in a similar error message regardless of using capitalization of S and C, and regardless of using double quotation marks.

Comment: Very strange because for me that works well, like in this simulation: https://dbfiddle.uk/6CryM1Pz

Comment: Thank you for confirming, it does seem that my table is (somehow) broken. Perhaps I will try to make a copy without the tsvector column.